# how to make a report from a sql table by giving some data

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a MySQL table of different match record. Now I want to make result that shows the total matches, win matches and lost matches by our desire team against different teams that had played with our desire team 
And I have explained my problem in a picture that is in [image: link]

Comment: That is a very unspecific question. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Welcome to SO.This is not the site, which converts a problem description into codes/queries. Show what you have tried and tells us where you failed.

Comment: if you understand what I am try to ask than you can make such query

Comment: [The tips on how to ask questions on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help you to organize your thoughts and to ask more precise questions. That, in turn, will result in a speedier answer from the community, and a more useful reference from others.

Comment: not clear what u r asking?

Answer (score 0):

Try once...

```
select tmat.t1 as 'Team',sum(`total Match`) as `total Match`, 
(select count(*) `total win` from tmatch where tmatch.w = tmat.t1) as `Total Win`, 
(select count(*) `total loss` from tmatch where tmatch.l = tmat.t1) as `Total loss`

 from (
SELECT t1,count(*) `total Match` from tmatch group by t1
union all
SELECT t2 ,count(*) `total Match` from tmatch group by t2) tmat group by tmat.t1
```